# Code not working in Windows Service project

Tags: c#, vb.net

Hey guys, I'm currently starting work on my first windows service and I've encountered what I find to be a strange error. For some reason the compiler is telling me that a whole bunch of typical classes (such as Image, Bitmap, Graphics, etc) do not exist. For example, these simple lines of code, which work perfectly in a normal project, return a bunch of errors:

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight); //Error 13    The type or namespace name 'Bitmap' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)b); //Error 17   The type or namespace name 'Image' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic; //Error 18  The name 'InterpolationMode' does not exist in the current context
```

Any ideas? (I have a feeling this is a simple answer, but I absolutely need these classes in my service)

Comment: i'm geussing you have a host project for the service, and another class library project with some logic. maybe you didnt reference the proper assemblies in your host project ?

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you have referenced the `System.Drawing` assembly to your project. The [Graphics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.aspx) class is defined inside this assembly.

Comment: I have "using System.Drawing;" at the top of my file. This .cs file is literally the exact same from another project, where it worked perfectly.

Comment: @Rob, not the using section, you need to [add a reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(v=vs.80).aspx) to the System.Drawing assembly by right clicking on the References folder in the project.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I knew it was something silly...still getting used to c# from c++